# Decode zookeeper 'data' from transaction log

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

I was able to decode the transaction logs using java -cp zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar org.apache.zookeeper.server.LogFormatter

I have a problem when I have to decode the 'data' part of the transaction.
The data starts with '#' followed by string. How do I decode this to a human readable format?

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the data had an a layer of hex encoding on top of the zookeeper encoding.